# Prestashop custom module add table header

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am developing a custom module in Prestashop. In that module I want to show my custom saved values like the table order. So basically the table should have header part and in that header part there would input fields to search the record for the corresponding data header. So the module custom page header should show like this reference image[image]

So can some one tell me how to do this in a custom module? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You need some effort to make it all work but for displaying table header, and I do hope you are using HelperList class,

```
$helper->simple_header = false;
```

Check [official documentation](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/HelperList#HelperList-Sortableheader).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know how to make a module, all you need is this (bear in mind it is an example and you'll have to replace bits and pieces here and there).

file `/modules/mymodule/controllers/admin/AdminRulesController.php`

```
class AdminRulesController extends ModuleAdminController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->module = 'mymodule'; 
        $this->table = 'rules'; //table queried for the list
        $this->className = 'Rules';//class of the list items
        $this->lang = false;
        $this->bootstrap = true;
        $this->context = Context::getContext();

        $this->fields_list = array(
            'id_rule' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('ID'),
                'align' => 'center',
                'class' => 'fixed-width-xs',
                'search' => false, //in case you want certain fields to not be searchable/sortable
                'orderby' => false,
            ),
            'name' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Rule name'),
                'align' => 'center',
            ),
            'is_active' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Active'),
                'align' => 'center',
                'type' => 'bool',
                'active' => 'status',
            ),
            'comment' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Comment'),
                'align' => 'center',
                'callback' => 'displayOrderLink' //will allow you to display the value in a custom way using a controller callback (see lower)
            )
        );

        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function renderList()
    {
        $this->addRowAction('edit');
        $this->addRowAction('delete');
        return parent::renderList();
    }

    public function displayOrderLink($comment)
    {
        switch($comment)
        {
            case 'value1':
                return '<span style="color:red">mytext</span>';
            case 'value2':
                return '<strong>mytext</strong>';
            default:
                return 'defaultValue';
        }
    }
}
```